# Getting error as " SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected "

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to select records from database using php PDO, but getting error as "SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected".
I found some similar available solutions, but unfortunately these are not resolved my problem.

Here is my code

```
class Database {
     private $servername = "127.0.0.1";
     private $username = "root";
     private $password = "";
     private $dbname = 'demo';
     protected static $con = null;

     function __construct() {
        try {
            self::$con = new PDO( "mysql:host = $this->servername;dbname = $this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password );
            self::$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $stmt = self::$con->prepare("select * from test");
            $stmt->execute();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                print_r($row);
            }
        } catch( PDOException $e ) {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            die;
        }
     }
}
```

when I am executing the above code I am getting the mentioned error.
Can anyone please let me know, what exactly i missed out here?

Comment: Get rid of the spaces in your DSN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your connection string do this:

```
self::$con = new PDO( "mysql:host={$this->servername};dbname={$this->dbname}", $this->username, $this->password );
```

It will help php to parse your variables correctly.

Or use concatenation:

```
self::$con = new PDO( "mysql:host=" . $this->servername . ";dbname=" . $this->dbname, $this->username, $this->password );
```

And as shown in the manual - I removed all spaces in dsn.

Comment: PHP can parse `$object->property` within a double quoted string just fine.

Comment: `php -r '$obj = new stdClass; $obj->foo="bar"; echo "Here is a property: $obj->foo\n";'`